# how could we get friendly error page when we type url with wrong port to apache server on linux

Tags: apache, http, https

I have an apache server on linux machine which listen at: 
http://:8080
it will redirect to https://:8082

my question is how could we get the friendly error page when we access: 
http://:8082 
//wrong port

till now we will have the info in web browser status bar: 
"waiting for http://:8082...", 
and no response in long time.

you know, the port 8082 is special because it is used for https connection, if we access: http://:8083, it will return with error(HTTP 400 Bad Request) quickly.

thanks, 
Emre

Comment: @tecknolagi: i don't think custom 400 page will solve his problem. Cause Emre is saying that he is not getting response.

Comment: yes, long time "waiting for http://<server_ip>:8082...", then empty page from IE. 
by chrome, i can get "ERROR 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):unknown error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should propably be in serverfault but here's a reply anyway.

Multiple ways to archive what you are after, none of them which is particulary great. But if i'd really really have to do that i'd do it like this

1. your website should be running with linux & you should have root access
2. setup a virtual host in apache on arbituary port which will only reply with that error message about wrong port.
3. setup iptables rules to forward all connection on ports x,y,z which are "wrong" ports to the port where the virtualhost you configured  is running.

Comment: it is an interesting workaround solution, thanks. but i am wondering if we have some configuration update to solve it on apache side?

Comment: There's no configuration options in apache that would do what you are really after.  As the thing is, the port you specify in the url is happening on tcp level way before anything that apache handles by itself, However, you could add listen/bind on multiple ports and then you just rince and repeat part 2  for all the ports want your message to be printed.

Comment: thanks for your precise response, but i have one question, as you said, "the port you specify in the url is happening on tcp level way before anything that apache handles by itself," why different result if we access port 8082 and 8083? is there any reason that port 8082 is used for ssl, so it has something special treatment?

Comment: Protocol part of the url defines the the usage of ssl, not the port.  One can attach apache to any port and associate it with either http or https (ssl).  There are predefined "standards" that suggest a certain protocols to be used with certain tcp ports but there is no harcoded requirement to do that.  For example default http (non-ssl) port is 80 - and default https (ssl) port os 443.  The port usage of  8082 & 8083 makes me think that you have a tomcat (or other webapp server?)

Comment: And that instance which responds to those ports (specially the one that takes a really long to respond) is doing a reverse dns lookup.   But  even if its not a tomcat or similar, if the machine is not under heavy load and responds well in other ways, long response time is most often about really slow dns lookups.  Check your resolver configurations.

Comment: " Check your resolver configurations." could you help to figure out which detailed part i should check? because from different pc or laptops, we get the same situation: long time to wait, thanks!